# C# MySQL Error “Column count doesn't match value count at row 1”

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0

```
 MySqlCommand cmd1 =
                    new MySqlCommand(
                        "INSERT INTO quotedetails (name, address, district, date, forto, refto, total) VALUES('" + txttoname.Text + "', '" + txttoaddress.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />").ToString() + "', '" + txtdistrict.Text + "' , '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +"', '" + txtfor.Text + "', '" + txtref.Text + "', '" + txttotal.Text + "')", conn);
                {
```

Can I get some help please? Im getting Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 when the command1 is executed.

Comment: Start by escaping your input properly.

Comment: Let me explain briefly please. because am new to database. @shmosel

Answer (score 1):

You should never use SQLs like this. It is prone to SQL Injection attacks. When you use it like yours, one can steal confidential information from database or even delete your tables, data etc. For details please read [SQL Injection on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Instead you should use parameterized SQL queries. In that way you are safe from injection attacks and I believe it is much more practical to write sql.

In your case entering single ' char into one of the textboxes will cause your query to get exception. To fix the issue just use prameters.

For your case  you can write something like that.

```
string sqlString = @"INSERT INTO quotedetails (
                            name, 
                            address, 
                            district, 
                            date, 
                            forto, 
                            refto, 
                            total) 
                        VALUES (
                            @PAR_name, 
                            @PAR_address,
                            @PAR_district,
                            @PAR_date,
                            @PAR_forto,
                            @PAR_refto,
                            @PAR_total)";
    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(sqlString, conn);

    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("PAR_name", txttoname.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("PAR_address", txttoaddress.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />"));
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("PAR_district", txtdistrict.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("PAR_date", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("PAR_forto", txtfor.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("PAR_refto", txtref.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("PAR_total", txttotal.Text);
```

Please note that I use prefix *PAR_* for my sql parameters, it is just a convention you can use that or skip *PAR_* prefix does not matter and it is all about naming habits.

Additionaly; in a parameterized query, you don't need to convert all your values to string. You can use DateTime for your date field or you can pass int variable without using ToString() as you do before.

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it, this happens when the number of values are more or less than columns provided.

From your statement, this does not seem to be the case. BUT since you are providing uielements directly into insert statement (Textbook case of SQL Injection), I am guessing there is a single quote `'` in any of your ui elements, which breaks your insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
MySqlCommand cmd1  = conn.CreateCommand();

cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO quotedetails (name, address, district, date, forto, refto, total) VALUES('" + txttoname.Text + "', '" + txttoaddress.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />").ToString() + "', '" + txtdistrict.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +"', '" + txtfor.Text + "', '" + txtref.Text + "', '" + txttotal.Text + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL parameters will save you from lots of trouble as well as SQL injection.I am quite sure that if you use parameters your problem will be resolved:

```
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand( "INSERT INTO quotedetails (name, address, district, date, forto, refto, total) VALUES(@name,@address,@district,@date,@forto,@refto,@total)", conn);

cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",txttoname.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address",+ txttoaddress.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />").ToString());
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@district",txtdistrict.Text);
...
```